# EF equivalent of nHibernate Formula mapping

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate

I am working on some legacy nHibernte code which the company has decided to move to EF. I have found fluent mapping using a formula map and would like to  replicate this in EF (6.*). As I understand formula mapping is not available in EF but was hoping for someone to provide a *simple* solution or workaround.

Simplified Entity:

```
public class Department
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool CanChange { get; set; }        
}
```

Simplified nHibernate Map:

```
public DepartmentMap()
{
    Map(x => x.Name);
    Map(x => x.CanChange)
      .Formula("(select case when count(*) > 0 then 0 else 1 end from Users where Users.placeid = Id)");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the database?

This looks like a candidate for a (non-persisted) [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table).

Add the column then map it as a regular property and mark it as readonly.

You will need to create a function for the query as it uses another table

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getCanChangeDepartment(@placeId int)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @r bit

    select @r = case when count(0) > 0 then cast(0 as bit) 
     else cast(1 as bit) end 
     from Users 
     where Users.placeid = @placeId

    RETURN @r
END

ALTER TABLE dbo.Department
   ADD CanChange AS dbo.getCanChangeDepartment(Id)
```

Comment: I should not change the database but I will anyway. I like your approach and agree that there is no reason for the ORM to do things that the database can do better and faster.

Comment: just thought of another approach (see below)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a View that returns all departments and whether they can be changed.

Map with EF.

Create a 1-to-1 Join relationship with Department.